# Parse Basic Queries Unity 5.3.0f4

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I'm using Parse, and I try to make a query. I get an error with this code:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore")
    .WhereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
});
```

I get this error on `IEnumerable<ParseObject>`:

> The non-generic type System.colletions.IEnumerable cannot be used with the type arguments

Comment: Do you have `using System.Collections.Generic;` in your script? It's just referencing the wrong class.